# PHP Get JSON POST Data

Tags: php, json, http

I've setup a Webhook to get notifications posted to a PHP page on my server. The notification request to my server is like this:

```
POST /message/receive HTTP/1.1
Host: http://www.yoururl.com/zipwhip/api/receive
Content-Length: 581
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{ "body":"Thanks for texting, this is an auto reply!",
  "bodySize":42,
  "visible":true,
  "hasAttachment":false,
  "dateRead":null,
  "bcc":null,
  "finalDestination":"4257772300",
  "messageType":"MO",
  "deleted":false,
"statusCode":4,
"id":634151298329219072, "scheduledDate":null, "fingerprint":"132131532", "messageTransport":9, "contactId":3382213402, "address":"ptn:/4257772222",
"read" "dateCreated":"2015-08-19T16:53:45-07:00", "dateDeleted":null,
  "dateDelivered":null,
  "cc":null,
  "finalSource":"4257772222",
} "dev
```

I've tried using the following to convert the JSON data to a string that I can work with, but I'm getting nothing so far:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );
```

Everything I've read indicates this should work - I tested the following and this is actually working:

```
$webhookContent = "";

    $webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
    while (!feof($webhook)) {
        $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
    }
    fclose($webhook);
```

I'm trying to understand why file_get_contents('php://input'); doesn't work when everything I've read indicates that's the function I should be using, and why fopen('php://input' , 'rb'); works instead?

If I do var_dump($inputJSON) I get:

```
    string(527) "{ "body":"Thanks for texting, this is an auto reply!",
  "bodySize":42,
  "visible":true,
  "hasAttachment":false,
  "dateRead":null,
  "bcc":null,
  "finalDestination":"4257772300",
  "messageType":"MO",
  "deleted":false,
"statusCode":4,
"id":634151298329219072, "scheduledDate":null, "fingerprint":"132131532", "messageTransport":9, "contactId":3382213402, "address":"ptn:/4257772222",
"read" "dateCreated":"2015-08-19T16:53:45-07:00", "dateDeleted":null,
  "dateDelivered":null,
  "cc":null,
  "finalSource":"4257772222",
}"
```

var_dump($input) returns NULL

Comment: So what is not working, what does `var_dump($inputJSON)` give you?

Comment: Your JSON does not look valid to me.

Comment: @jeroen I've edited the question to include the result of var_dump($inputJSON)

Comment: That's not valid json. How are you creating it?

Comment: It seems like it's a serialized data but not a json data, try php's serialize() and  unserialize() instead of json_****() functions...

Comment: @jeroen the JSON data is coming from an external web service. I've tried replicating their request using cURL locally and getting same issue. It looks like the content length (the string(527) at the beginning of the var_dump($inputJSON) value). It looks like the file_get_contents('php://input'); is returning the content length as well? Is this normal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following is working for me now:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON );
```

I think my issue was using:

```
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );
```

instead of just:

```
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON );
```